# Converting values of dictionary into array in the consecutive order (python)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My objective is **converting a dictionary of the label id and label name into an array in consecutive order** same as the dictionary.

Here's codes and outcome from getting dict from a dataframe.

**CODE:**

```
classes_with_id = {id: labels for id, labels in zip(train['Human_CategoryID'], train['Human_Category'])}
classes_with_id
```

**OUTCOME:**

[image]

When I get values from the dict and put into an array I got this outcome.

**Code:**

```
classes_array = [label for label in classes_with_id.values()]
classes_array
```

**Outcome:**

[image]

You can see that the first index of the array is 'Call Center',
and I would like to have 'Accessibility' as the first index of the array
(same consecutive order of values in the dict)

How to make them in order same as the values in dictionary?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution found with these easy code:

1. Create empty the string array based on the range of labels

> classes_array = ["" for x in range(len(classes_with_id))]

2. Put label ids-1 as the index of the array and make them equal to each label.

> ```
> for id, label in classes_with_id.items():
>   classes_array[id-1] = label
> ```

Comment: But here if **classes_with_id ={1:"assebility",3:"company brand",4:"staff",5:"product and sevid",2:"facility"}**
and we use same code then output will be like this:
**['assebility', 'facility', 'company brand', 'staff', 'product and sevid']**
sequence of facility changed

Comment: Agree. maybe sort the key dict first before using this method. Thank you Hiral.

Comment: Still if one number missing in keys then it will return error

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
a ={1:"assebility",2:"facility",3:"company brand",4:"staff",5:"product and sevid"}
lista =[]
for k,v in a.items():
    lista.append(v)
    
print(lista)
```

output:

```
['assebility', 'facility', 'company brand', 'staff', 'product and sevid']
```

Comment: I got like this. ['Staff, Service and Take Ownership', 'Accessibility', 'Staff Management', 'Timing, Waiting Time and Queue Management', 'No category', 'Staff, Manner and Appearance', 'Staff, Sale Process', 'Product and Service, System', 'Timing, Service Time', 'Staff, Sensible', 'Product and Service, Variety', 'Facility', 'Product and Service, ...]

Comment: Can you write input?? so i can copy paste your data

Comment: @Setthawut Kulsrisuwan I got thye same output as you want with your data. Which IDE are you using??

Comment: using Google colab

Comment: @Setthawut Kulsrisuwan
 It is also working fine and gives same output